# Remove any numbers at the front of a file name or remove the first two numbers for Mac

Tags: file, macos

I have a thousand files that are named like this...

01 heartbeat a.wav
02 heartbeat b.wav
03 heartbeat c.wav

I'm looking for a terminal command that will remove the numbers at the front of the name.
And when I use the code do I start with

"cd_" 
drop the folder in terminal
enter
"ls"
enter
Copy and paste the command?

Thank you!!

Comment: If it doesn't need to be done through terminal, I'd suggest: [Better Rename](https://www.publicspace.net/BetterRename/). In your case, you'd probably need to use the regex action from the advanced & special category and use a pattern to match the numbers in the front only `^[0-9]+ `. One reason why I would recommend this app for this case is its droplet feature. You can basically save your rename actions into an application that you can drag files into to rename them. It can also rename nested files while ignoring folders.

Comment: Maybe this doesn't fit your use case at all, but I love that I can save this droplet into a project folder with it's specific rename needs and drop in the. In some cases I've also had [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/) watch a folder and open the files in this droplet application to rename new files when they're added. Of course you don't need Better Rename in this workflow either...

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102974/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-a-macos-terminal) recommends you install [rename](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename) via [brew](https://brew.sh/).